# SQL underscore in LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-like

programmers !

I didn't actually face the problem, but I was wondering how to do something...
If I wanted to find data beginning by an `a` and having 3 characters in total, I would write:

```
SELECT Client_ID
FROM Clients
WHERE Client_ID LIKE 'a__'
```

My question is, what if I want a word that contains 3 characters, with `_` as the first character. How can I make my code understand that the first character is an underscore, and not just whatever character that exist ?

The code below would just give me any word containing 3 characters, whatever they are. But what if I want a client_ID starting with '_' and then containing 2 other characters ?

```
SELECT Client_ID
FROM Clients
WHERE Client_ID LIKE '___'
```

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Did you read your database program's documentation for LIKE?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Client_ID
FROM Clients
WHERE Client_ID LIKE '\_\_\_';
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to escape the _ using [_] and then add the remaining ___ to capture the 3 characters. Something like this maybe:

select Client_ID
from Clients
where ClientID like '[_]___%'

Hope it helps!!

Comment: This works on MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the wildcards in `LIKE` patterns.  I usually define the escape character explicitly:

```
WHERE Client_ID LIKE '$___' ESCAPE '$'
```

The default escape character is a backslash, so this should work as well:

```
WHERE Client_ID LIKE '\___'
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work :

```
SELECT Client_ID
FROM Clients
WHERE regexp_like(Client_ID,'^_{1}(.){2}$');
```